# Возведение в степень не работает

Tags: c++

Обычная задача по возведению в степень. Есть 2 функции. Подскажите, почему при значениях x = 0.00001
        n = 2147483647 работает только первая (вторая не проходит по времени)? ведь идет простое перемножение.

```
double myPow1(double x, int n) {
    if(n==1)
        return x;
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    if(n==-1)
        return 1/x;
    if(n==2)
        return x*x;
    return myPow(myPow(x, n/2), 2)* myPow(x, n%2);
}

double myPow2(double x, int n){
    double result = 1;
    if (n>=0){
        while (n-->=1) {
            result *= x;
        }
    }
    else {
        while (n++<0) {
            result /= x;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Потому что на первую уходит порядка 30 операций, а на вторую порядка 2^30 операций. Разница весьма существенна.

Comment: Потому-что у первой логарифмическая сложность (O(log N) ), а у второй - линейная ( O(N) ).

Comment: "ведь идет простое перемножение". Нет, в первом варианте идет совсем не простое перемножение.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритмы_быстрого_возведения_в_степень

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая работает за О(log2(n)), вторая за О(n). Допустим нужно 2 ^ 16. Первая посчитает это (((2 ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2. Итого 4 действий. 4 = log2(16). На самом деле их несколько больше, но логарифмическая зависимости остаётся. Для 2147483647 понадобится порядка log2(2147483647) = 31 операций. Во втором же способе будет честно 2147483647 умножений. Правда ответ будет достаточно неверный ни там, ни там. Он просто в double не влезет. Минимальное положительное число у double ≈ 2.2*e-308. А 0.00001 ^ 2147483647 сильно меньше.